# Section over another section

Tags: html, css

I need a section(**tabs**) to be over an section(**showcase**). Right now, the tabs section is right below showcase.

```
<section id="showcase">

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Střední průmyslová škola elektrotechnická</h1>
</section>

<section id="tabs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="images/proUchazece.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="images/proUchazece.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="images/proUchazece.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="images/proUchazece.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS Now:

```
#showcase h1{margin-top: 350px;font-size: 32px;  color: white;text-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;}

#showcase{background: url("../images/showbar.png");text-align: center;min-height: 500px;position: relative;}

#tabs .box{display: inline-block;  margin: 0 5px;}

#tabs { text-align: center;}
```

[How it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISrsf.png)

[How I need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPtcK.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Z-index style determines the overlay order.  I added it to your css below.

```
#showcase h1{margin-top: 350px;font-size: 32px;  color: white;text-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;}

#showcase{background: url("../images/showbar.png");text-align: center;min-height: 500px;position: relative; z-index:1;}

#tabs .box{display: inline-block;  margin: 0 5px; z-index:2;}

#tabs { text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to shift the orange boxes up, right?
There's multiple way of achiving that. One is using a negative `margin-top`:

```
#tabs {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Another method is setting the relative position. This will not change the box model, so elements coming after the boxes will not go up to fill the space:

```
#tabs {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
```

Choose whichever fits your use case better.